# Creating a list of outputs from a function with unknown number of variables and possible variable values

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Let me start with a quick example:

```
def my_fun(dict):
  # do stuff
  return

dict_1 = { "A": np.arange(0,4,1), "B": np.arange(10, 20, 1), "C": np.arange(3,13,2) }

for a in dict_1["A"]:
  for b in dict_1["B"]:
    for c in dict_1["C"]:
      temp_dict = {"A": a, "B": b, "C": c}
      my_fun(temp_dict)
```

The problem is that I have almost 200 different dictionaries: `dict_2`, `dict_3`, etc.

Each dict has different numbers of different keys and the arrays in them are all different.

I'm hoping to get a single script that loops through any arbitrary dictionary (of the structure `{key1: array1, key2: array2, ...}`) and runs my_fun on each possible iteration of the different values of the different arrays, so I don't have to write 200 different loops.

Comment: You can use `itertools.product()` to generate all the combinations of arbitrary sequences.

Comment: @Barmar I was looking at that but maybe I’m missing something. Can I make a dictionary variable from it, like I do with ‘temp_dict’ in my example? I need to know what value comes from what key.

Comment: If you have a list of the keys and values, you can use `temp_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! If you put it as an answer including the zip, I’ll accept it or I’ll put it as an answer in a bit if you don’t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar for the help in his comments.

```
from itertools import product

it = product(*(dict_1[key] for key in dict_1.keys()))
for t in it:
  temp_dict = dict(zip(d.keys(), t))
  my_fun(temp_dict)
```

Where `*` in `product` creates the arguments.